# How to find missing dates in an excel file by python

Tags: python, excel

I'm a beginner in python. I have an excel file. This file shows the rainfall amount between 2016-1-1 and 2020-6-30. It has 2 columns. The first column is date, another column is rainfall. Some dates are missed in the file (The rainfall didn't estimate). For example there isn't a row for 2016-05-05 in my file. This a sample of my excel file.

```
Date         rainfall (mm)
1/1/2016       10
1/2/2016       5
.
.
.
12/30/2020     0
```

I want to find the missing dates but my code doesn't work correctly!

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from matplotlib import dates as mpl_dates
from matplotlib.dates import date2num

df=pd.read_excel ('rainfall.xlsx')
a= pd.date_range(start = '2016-01-01', end = '2020-06-30' ).difference(df.index)
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_excel('rainfall.xlsx', usecols=[0])
a = pd.date_range(start = '2016-01-01', end = '2020-06-30').difference([l[0] for l in df.values])
print(a)
```

And the date in the file must like `2016/1/1`

Answer (score 1):

Here' a beginner friendly way of doing it.

First you need to make sure, that the Date in your dataframe is really a date and not a string or object.

Type (or print) `df.info()`.

The date column should show up as `datetime64[ns]`

If not, `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=False)`fixes that. (Use dayfirst to tell if the month is first or the day is first in your date string because Pandas doesn't know. Month first is the default, if you forget, so it would work without...)

For the tasks of finding missing days, there's many ways to solve it. Here's one.

Turn all dates into a series

```
all_dates = pd.Series(pd.date_range(start = '2016-01-01', end = '2020-06-30' ))
```

Then print all dates from that series which are not in your dataframe "Date" column. The `~` sign means "not".

```
print(all_dates[~all_dates.isin(df['Date'])])
```

Answer (score 0):

To find the missing dates from a list, you can apply Conditional Formatting function in Excel. 4. Click OK > OK, then the position of the missing dates are highlighted. Note: The last date in the date list will be highlighted.
this TRICK Is not with python,a NORMAL Trick

Comment: can you explain more how can I find the missing dates in excel?